# css3 rotate not coming back on hovering out

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I am rotating an image by css3 `transform`

```
#services .info img{
-ms-transform: rotate(0deg) rotateY(0); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) rotateY(0); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: rotate(0deg) rotateY(0); /* Opera */
-moz-transform:rotate(0deg) rotateY(0); /* Firefox */
transform: rotate(0deg) rotateY(0);


}


#services .info img:hover{ -ms-transform: rotate(360deg) rotateY(0); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) rotateY(0); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: rotate(360deg) rotateY(0); /* Opera */
-moz-transform:rotate(360deg) rotateY(0); /* Firefox */
transform: rotate(360deg) rotateY(0); transition:.3s;
}
```

problem is that the image is not rotating back when I hover out of the element.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is not that it is jot rotating back, the real problem is that it does so instantly.

You need to se the transition on tha base element to apply it both on hover-in and on hover-out

This CSS works:

```
#test {
    width: 60px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg); /* Opera */
    -moz-transform:rotate(0deg); /* Firefox */
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .3s;   
    transition: .3s;   
}

#test:hover {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg); /* Opera */
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg); /* Firefox */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/rzuAE/1/)